# easing on self executed loop

Tags: jquery, animation, easing

i want to add an easing function to a custom made loop, anyone knows how i can modify the interval time regarding to an easing function?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbt245gv/

easings: https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js

```
var running  = true,
    count    = 0,
    maxcount = 100
    interval = 30
;

(function executer() {
    // ...do stuff while running = true
    // if condition hits set running to false
    count++;
    $('.logger').html(count)
    if (count >= maxcount) {
        running = false;
    }
    // stop the loop if condition hits
    if (running) {
        window.testtimer = window.setTimeout(executer,interval);
    }
})();
```